# Internet Explorer Developer Tools does not show source code using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, requirejs, amd

I am attempting to debug a page issue where IE 9 will work the first time on my requirejs/backbone application, but will fail on the page reload. However, when I attempt to debug this problem using the f12 IE developer tools, I cannot navigate to the source to set a breakpoint because IE does not load any of the files that RequireJS includes. How can I get around this issue to fix my IE headache??

Comment: Does clicking the refresh icon in the HTML tab make a difference?

Comment: It does refresh all the script tags that requirejs has written to the dom in the HTML view. However, the script tab does not reflect these new scripts (can't see them)

Answer (score 4):

I guess I am late for the party but hope my answer helps you and others as well.
The file that you want to debug or the line in the file, simply add this --> `debugger;`
before that line.

So, when require.js loads your script and encounter that string i.e. `debugger;` exists it will automatically be stopped at that line.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a single js File with require tools :

- include requirejs in this single file
  (http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#onejs)
- set optimise to
  none (no source minified -
  http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#shallow)

In your index.html link this file instead of require.js.

You can debug with IE.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem from time to time. What sometimes helps: Close all the files in Debugger view, leave the DevTools open, press Play to allow page to continue and then make your action on the page or reload - if it halts on the **debugger;** again, all the files will be loaded. But still investigating ;)